# The positive-definiteness of the special matrix created by shifting the vector $[1\, \cdots \, n\, \cdots\,1]$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-definite

I am wondering if there is a good way to prove if matrices with the following structure are positive definite:
\begin{equation}
\left[
\begin{array}{ccccccc}
10 &9 &8 &\cdots &3 &2 &1\\
9  &10 &9 &\cdots &4 &3 &2\\
8 &9 &10 &\cdots &5 &4 &3\\
\vdots &\vdots &\vdots &\ddots &\vdots &\vdots &\vdots \\
3 &4 &5 &\cdots &10 &9 &8\\
2 &3 &4 &\cdots &9 &10 &9\\
1 &2 &3 &\cdots &8 &9 &10
\end{array}
\right]
\end{equation}
Basically, each row is created by shifting the vector $[1\, \cdots \, n\, \cdots\,1]$. Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll just do the $n=10$ example.

Consider the vectors $v_1=(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)$,
$v_2=(0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)$,
$v_3=(0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)$ up to
$v_{10}=(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1)$. These are linearly
independent, and their Gram matrix is your matrix, which is therefore
positive definite.

In more detail, let $x=(x_1,\ldots,x_{10})$ be a nonzero row vector,
then $w=x_1v_1+\cdots+x_{10}v_{10}$ is nonzero, so $|w|^2>0$. But
$|w|^2=xAx^t$ where $A$ is your matrix. So your matrix is positive-definite.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was also trying to find such a set of vectors, but I was only thinking about vectors of length 10......